# How do I get the original key in count for loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I need to loop through a keyed json array in jquery with a count++ loop how do I access the original keys within the loop so I can compare to next and previous?

```
var json = [{"key1":{"value":"33"},"key2":{"value":"36 "},"key3":{"value":"38"},"key4":{"value":"41"}}]

json = json[0];
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
//I need to compare original this key next key and previous key here.
e.g. how do I get from json[i] to key2 when i=1
// How do I get the original key using the numeric key here
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON. That's just an array.

Comment: Your `json` variable refers to an array with **one** entry in it, which is an object. Is that really what your structure is?

Comment: typo jsonList = json, editied to fix

Comment: no I meant jsonlist is json was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I get from json[i] to key2 when i=1

With your existing code, you'd have to store the result of `Object.keys` so you could use it again:

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i]); // key1, key2, etc.
}
```

*(Well, you don't **have** to, you could call `Object.keys` repeatedly, but that's probably not a good idea.)*

Comment: ...but it seems like if you told us what you wanted to do in the loop, we may well be able to offer a better way to do it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Object.keys(json[0])` as this is an array with on object element having properties??

Comment: That returns the value rather than the key.

I'm trying to loop through json to compare if the key of each object is >= to previous key and < than than the key of the next object, returning the value if it is.